# Are versions of the Spring frramework < 5.05 vulnerable to CVE-2018-1258

Tags: spring, spring-security

A Spring security CVE (https://pivotal.io/security/cve-2018-1258) has recently been discovered and it states that users of the following libraries are impacted:

Spring Framework 5.0.5.RELEASE + Spring Security (any version)

(From the above link)

Does this mean that versions of the Spring framework < 5.0.5 also have the same vulnerability, or was there a change in 5.0.5 that exposed the vulnerability?

I have not been able to find any information about what the vulnerability actually is.